# Display date time in Java with Thai numerals

Tags: java, datetime, localization, datetime-format

This exercise comes from Horstmann's book *Core Java for the impatient*:

> Write a program that demonstrates the date and time formatting styles in [...] Thailand (with Thai digits).

I tried to solve the exerciese with the following snippet:

```
    Locale locale =  Locale.forLanguageTag("th-TH-TH");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
    System.out.println(formatter.withLocale(locale).format(dateTime));
```

The problem is that while the name of month  is given properly in Thai (at least I think so, since I don't know Thai), the numbers are still formatted with Arabic numerals, the output is as follows:

> 3 ก.ย. 2017, 22:42:16

I tried different language tags (`"th-TH"`, `"th-TH-TH"`, `"th-TH-u-nu-thai"`) to no avail. What should I change to make the program behave as desired? I use JDK 1.8.0_131 on Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Good question and answer. But FYI, [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) purposely discards time zone information. Better to use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and retain that valuable info. Also better to explicitly pass your desired/expected time zone to either class’ `.now( ZoneId )` method rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone that can be changed at any moment during runtime.

Comment: This is a useful question and answer, but it still leaves me wondering how you're ever going to verify that the code is correct if you can't understand the output.  :)

Comment: @ajb Output looks convincingly non-Western for me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `DateTimeFormatter::withDecimalStyle`

I was able to solve the exercise. One must pass a [`DecimalStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DecimalStyle.html) to the formatter by calling [`DateTimeFormatter::withDecimalStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withDecimalStyle-java.time.format.DecimalStyle-), like this (see the code in **bold** for changes):

```
    Locale locale =  Locale.forLanguageTag("th-TH-u-nu-thai");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    DecimalStyle style = DecimalStyle.of(locale);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);            
    System.out.println(formatter.withLocale(locale).withDecimalStyle(style).format(dateTime));
```